# Running rails console suddenly stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

All of the sudden, Rails' console stopped working on one of my projects. I keep getting the following error:

```
rails c
Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
Could not find activesupport-4.1.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So I updated Rubygems, with the following two lines (from rubygems.com)

```
$ gem install rubygems-update  # again, might need to be admin/root
$ update_rubygems
```

and get the following output:

```
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.4.4
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-2.4.4
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

...

RubyGems 2.4.4 installed
Parsing documentation for rubygems-2.4.4
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-2.4.4
=== 2.4.4 / 2014-11-12
```

Aaaaaand, then I run `rails console` again, and just get the same error message again.

Thoughts?

Comment: just follow the hint and run `bundle install`, instead of installing new gems

Comment: The message also says to run `gem pristine --all` which will reinstall all the gems from the cache and recompile all native drivers in the gems. Updating the Rubygems code doesn't do this so you have to explicitly run the command.

Comment: Bundle install doesn't install anything new. Bundle update doesn't do anything either. I of course tried gem pristine --all...nope, doesn't work, still get these error messages.

Comment: Ok I just updated my ruby version after reading that Yosemite doesn't come with the latest. I had tried running bundle install and pristine dozens of times. Now, it started installed something, after updating ruby... we'll see.

Comment: Not running as sudo may have affected the process as well, although bundle install actually doesn't necessarily let you know it may have an effect.

Comment: My console is back!

Solution, apparently, was to update ruby to the latest version, and then running bundle install with sudo. How much sudo and the update had to do with it respectively, I'm not sure. Anyway, up and running. Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the problem only if you use rvm else just ignore it.

Navigate to the root path (where your rails app is located).

type in your command line;

```
rvm list
```

You will get something like:

```
rvm rubies

   jruby-1.7.11 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

If your default is not the current you have most likely changed it.
Try to change it back and run:

You can change it like so:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p451
```

When you get the right version you can make it permanent.

like so:

```
rvm --default use ruby-2.0.0-p451

bundle install
```

again.

Comment: That's exactly what I did (see comments to another answers), update to latest ruby and run bundle install again, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but maybe try:

`gem install activesupport -v 4.1.4`

Then try and run rails c again.

Comment: I did just know and I get a new error. Actually, I figured that would happened, I have already installed about 10 different gems to fix this error and rails console keeps stopping on a new missing gem. I was starting to think the rubygems versions was the root cause, hence the question.

Comment: And that is still my main theory, something caused this to happen, I have been running this project for 3 months now without these issues, just started today.

Comment: Did you recently change anything else? Upgrade your OS? If not, the only think I can say is that I would keep following the error trial (installing new gems).

Comment: I actually did upgrade my OS yes ... but it didn't affect any of my other projects. I can run rails console in other folders. But that must be it.... given that's the case, any advice?

Comment: ya. the ```gem pristine --all``` idea isn't bad at all. Also are you using rvm or rbenv for gem management? if so, you may want to to google that along with the os you upgraded to. It will probably lead you down a good path.

Comment: It did. Mainly it seems like the ruby version is wrong for Yosemite. After updating ruby, I ran all of them again (bundle install, pristine etc), and I've got my rails console back! :)

Comment: Congrats! Glad we could help. Please consider up voting and marking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

The message also says to run `gem pristine --all` which will reinstall all the gems from the cache and recompile all native drivers in the gems.

Updating the Rubygems code doesn't do this so you have to explicitly run the command.